# Sharing scope data in controller

Tags: angularjs

My spring mvc controller returns an object.
My scenario is:
On click of a button from one page say sample1.html load a new page say sample2.html in the form of a table.

In sample1.html with button1 and controller1--> after clicking button1-->I have the object(lets say I got it from backend) obtained in controller1.
But the same object should be used to display a table in sample2.html

How can we use this object which is in controller1 in sample2.html?

Comment: Could you paste some code, so we have some idea of what you've done so far?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use `factory` to share data between controllers

```
    <div ng-controller="CtrlOne"> 

      <button ng-click="submit()">submit</button>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="CtrlTwo">
       {{obj}}
    </div>

.controller('CtrlOne', function($scope, sampleFactory) {
      $scope.sampleObj = {
          'name': 'riz'
      }; //object u get from the backend
      $scope.submit = function() {
          sampleFactory.setObj($scope.sampleObj);
      }
  })
  .controller('CtrlTwo', function($scope, sampleFactory) {
      $scope.obj = sampleFactory.getObj();
  })
  .factory('sampleFactory', function() {
      var obj = {};
      return {
          setObj: function(_obj) {
              obj = _obj;
          },
          getObj: function() {
              return obj;
          }
      }
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a service to store the data, and inject it in your controllers. Then, when the value is updated, you can use a [broadcast event](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) to share it.

Here is a few example:

**HTML view**

```
<div ng-controller="ControllerOne">
  CtrlOne <input ng-model="message">
  <button ng-click="handleClick(message);">LOG</button>
</div>

<div ng-controller="ControllerTwo">
  CtrlTwo <input ng-model="message">
</div>
```

**Controllers**

```
function ControllerOne($scope, sharedService) {
  $scope.handleClick = function(msg) {
    sharedService.prepForBroadcast(msg);
  };
}

function ControllerTwo($scope, sharedService) {
  $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function() {
    $scope.message = sharedService.message;
  });
}
```

**Service**

```
myModule.factory('mySharedService', function($rootScope) {
  var sharedService = {};

  sharedService.message = '';

  sharedService.prepForBroadcast = function(msg) {
    this.message = msg;
    this.broadcastItem();
  };

  sharedService.broadcastItem = function() {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('handleBroadcast');
  };
  return sharedService;
});
```

### [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/st46wfk4/2/)